# ARM Template - conflicting update

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-rm-template

There is ARM template for provisioning two Azure Search services

```
"resources": [
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Search/searchServices",
  "name": "[parameters('serviceName')]",
  "apiVersion": "[parameters('serviceApiVersion')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
    },
    "replicaCount": 1,
    "partitionCount": 1,
    "hostingMode": "[parameters('hostingMode')]"
  }
},
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Search/searchServices",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceName'), 'secondary')]",
  "apiVersion": "[parameters('serviceApiVersion')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "sku": {
      "name": "[parameters('sku')]"
    },
    "replicaCount": 1,
    "partitionCount": 1,
    "hostingMode": "[parameters('hostingMode')]"
  }
}]
```

Deployment of ARM Template provisions one search service and fails another with response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unknown",
    "message": "There was a conflicting update. No change was made to the resource from this request. RequestId: b65a51b5-cd87-4dc5-82d9-9041ddd1c2dc",
    "target": null,
    "details": null
  }
}
```

Does anyone face issue like that?

Comment: What process are using to run your deployment? Azure client, powershell,azure portal? In the resource group check the deployments blade to see if theres an deployment already running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps search services cannot be concurrently provisioned in the same resource group.   Try adding a "dependsOn" property to the second search service.

Answer (score 0):

#### The issue

The search services don't rely on another, so a `dependsOn` property wouldn't be required. 
I think the problem is that your arm **syntax is invalid**.

I don't know which apiVersion you are using, but I cannot find any that has the same syntax...
(it resembles 2015-02-28 the most, but the `hostingMode` field is not allowed there).

#### Solution

Either use apiVersion 2015-02-28 without `hostingmode` or (if you need that field) use a newer apiVersion where "sku" is taken outside the "properties". The following works for me!

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Search/searchServices",
    "name": "parameters('serviceName')",
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-19",
    "location": "parameters('location')",
    "properties": {
      "replicaCount": 1,
      "partitionCount": 1,
      "hostingMode": "default"
    },
    "sku": {
      "name": "basic"
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.Search/searchServices",
    "name": "[concat(parameters('serviceName'), 'secondary')]"
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-19",
    "location": "parameters('location')",
    "properties": {
      "replicaCount": 1,
      "partitionCount": 1,
      "hostingMode": "default"
    },
    "sku": {
      "name": "basic"
    }
  }]
}
```